# How to fix ob_end_flush() failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1)?

Tags: wp-admin

the following code appears at the bottom of my admin page:

```
ob_end_flush(): `failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/benemota/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2619`
```

That line 2619:

```
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++ ) {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

I already disabled all plugins to see if there was a problem with one of them, but it continued anyway.

There is another detail, when I click on any plugin, my admin panel remains blank with the error code in the footer

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add a PHP line using Code Snippets.

```
remove_action( 'shutdown', 'wp_ob_end_flush_all', 1 );
```

Code Snippets link https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

Comment: thats great but it would be wonderful if you would tell else where to add code snippet.

Comment: that plugin is dangerous, and so is the need to use it, this answer could easily have not mentioned it and instead suggested placing it in a plugin or the theme